# VB Macro to find duplicates between two ranges of text

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know any VB so I am not able to even get started on this little macro for someone.

What we want to happen is the macro would change the color of any cell in "Column A" if the cell text appears anywhere in "Column B". (Exactly the same text match)

The cell values would be text and not numbers.

If this can be done easily without a macro that would be great too.

Anyone have any examples that I can easily edit to do what we are looking for or able to provide the code that would get me these results? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with conditional formatting and a custom formula.

Select column A and on 'Home, click 'Conditional Formatting' and create a new rule. Select 'Use formula to determine which cells to format'

In the formula box, type the following formula:

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1, B:B, 0))
```

Pick the format you want to have with the <kbd>Format...</kbd> button and hit <kbd>OK</kbd> an that should be it.

Comment: Thanks will give it a try now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2007 or later you can also do this by:

1. Go to the "Home" tab in the ribbon
2. Highlight the two columns
3. Select "Conditional Formatting" in the ribbon
4. Select "Highlight Cells Rules"
5. Select "Duplicate Values"
6. Pick your format. If you want a custom format select "Custom Format" in the right dropdown that is shown in the popup window.
7. Select "Ok"